# Java hashmap cannot find existing entry

Tags: java, csv

I am running into a very weird problem: I wrote a CSV parser where it reads the first row as headers, then creates a map where key is the header and value is the values in subsequent rows.

The issue is the map cannot seem to retrieve the value of the header of the first column. As seen here:
[image]

as you can see, "abc" is inside the HashMap entry #23, but when I am retrieving it, it would show as null.

I think it has something to do with my CSV file but why is the map entries showing up correctly on debugger but cannot retrieve?

my CSV file looks like this:

> abc,Data
>   Source,Entity,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24
>   NA,source1,entity1,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124

Comment: Does it can be retrieved during the normal execution of your program, or the issue appears just when you try to resolve the expression during debugging?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: can you 'get' any other entries?

Comment: @ngueno it happens during normal execution, so I started to debug it and realized it is returning null on the `get()` for no clear reason.

Comment: @denov yes `get()` works on all other columns except the `abc` column which is the first column of the CSV file

Comment: i'd stick a breakpoint when you're inserting that key and inspect the value.  it may be a off by 1 mistake.  and some code would really be helpful :)

Comment: Are you sure that `abc` is actually `abc`? I mean, these are `а` and `c` in my language, which look similar, but are actually different. Check code for each char in the string.

Comment: Post more relevant info, like your parser and stuff, following @Slaw recommendation

Comment: thanks guys, I will try to reproduce it in a minimal setting and upload it to github to demo, is there an easier way to demo the problem?

Comment: Actually, how many characters does key `abc` have? It's possible that the file has some invisible character in the beginning (I encountered it few times because of some encoding stuff I don't really understand).

Comment: @dyukha it is originally using the word "Region" which didn't work either, so I don't think it is an text encoding issue, it only happens on the key that is in the first column of the CSV

Comment: It is obviously that get() can't find the key object because either hash() or equals() functions don't match. How do you create an entry in a hash map and what type are you using as a key?

Comment: @tom, so, does key `abc` have 3 characters?

Comment: _"my CSV file looks like this"_ ... are you _sure_ that's what the CSV file contains? As John Bollinger says, hex-edit (or hex-dump) the file to be sure. Is "Data Source" actually "Data<space>Source" or something else? CSV is more complex than most people think, and there are existing Java-based CSV parsers — maybe you should use one instead of writing your own.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only plausible explanation for the debugger results you observe is that the first column header is *not* actually `"abc"`.  It likely has one or more additional, non-printing characters within.  These do not print, naturally, in the debugger's list of the map's contents, but they are nevertheless there, so indeed the key `"abc"` is not present in the map.  It is actually something like `"<some_non-printing_character>abc"`.  Alternatively, it may be that you have different characters that are rendered the same on your display. Either way, examine the input file with a hex editor to see the truth.

The column in question being the first, a likely candidate for an extra character is a Unicode BOM, U+FEFF, appearing as the first character of the file.  Some text editors will insert such a character as a magic number marking files as being encoded in UTF-8, though in fact UTF-8 does not require that, and assigns no significance to such a character other than as itself.

Comment: thank you I think that is it, there is a `uFEFF' 65279` in char[0] of that key, now I just need to figure out how to get rid of it!